# Need examples headers and cookies

Tags: codenameone

IDE: NetBeans
Desktop OS Windows 10
Simulator Android/iOS
Device Android/iOS

I am able to get authentication to work with connection request. I am having to get header information and then in another part of the app, send that same information back to the cgi-bin. Below is my code and I commented on the parts where I believe I need to do something with a header and or cookie. I'm very new to this and It's been difficult finding even a basic header/cookie tutorial.

```
/**
 * Your application code goes here<br>
 * This file was generated by <a href="https://www.codenameone.com/">Codename One</a> for the purpose 
 * of building native mobile applications using Java.
 */


package userclasses;

import com.codename1.io.ConnectionRequest;
import com.codename1.io.Cookie;
import com.codename1.io.NetworkEvent;
import com.codename1.io.NetworkManager;
import com.codename1.io.Storage;
import com.codename1.notifications.LocalNotification;
import generated.StateMachineBase;
import com.codename1.ui.*; 
import com.codename1.ui.events.*;
import com.codename1.ui.util.Resources;


import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
//import org.apache.commons.httpclient.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
//import org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.AuthScope;

/**
 *
 * @John Barrett
 */
public class StateMachine extends StateMachineBase {
public StateMachine(String resFile) {
    super(resFile);
    // do not modify, write code in initVars and initialize class members there,
    // the constructor might be invoked too late due to race conditions that might occur
}

/**
 * this method should be used to initialize variables instead of
 * the constructor/class scope to avoid race conditions
 */
protected void initVars(Resources res) {
}
boolean stop = false;
boolean notify = false;
String OnOff;


@Override // Starts monitor action.
protected void onMain_ButtonAction(Component c, ActionEvent event){

    // starts a timer to repeat monitor every minute.
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    String text = (String) Storage.getInstance().readObject("SavedData");

    timer.schedule( new TimerTask(){


    @Override
    public void run(){       
    if (stop == true){
        cancel();//Monitor ends           
    } 

    //Starts a connection with the URL to monitor
    ConnectionRequest r = new ConnectionRequest();
    r.setUrl("http://vault.infinitevault.com/cgi-bin/absentmedia?customer=" + text.toLowerCase().trim());
    r.setPost(true);

    // Post Header/Cookie information to URL for access NEED HELP WITH THIS!
    r.setHttpMethod("HEAD");
    r.setContentType("text/xml");
    r.setCookiesEnabled(true);
    findCodeLabel(c).setText("Monitoring: " + text.toUpperCase());
    r.addResponseListener(new ActionListener(){

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev){



                    // Monitor starts 
                    try{

                    NetworkEvent event = (NetworkEvent) ev;
                    // Need to post header/cookie information here? HELP!
                    Cookie.isAutoStored();
                    byte[] data= (byte[]) event.getMetaData();
                    String decodedData = new String(data,"UTF-8");                           

                    boolean none;

                    none = decodedData.endsWith("NONE\n");


                    if (!none){                           



                    System.out.println(decodedData);                            

                        findCodeTextArea(c).setText(decodedData);

                        LocalNotification n = new LocalNotification();
                        n.setId("OSStorage");
                        n.setAlertBody(decodedData);
                        n.setAlertTitle("Absent Media");                

                        Display.getInstance().scheduleLocalNotification(
                                n,
                                System.currentTimeMillis() + 10 * 1000, // fire date/time
                                LocalNotification.REPEAT_MINUTE  // Whether to repeat and what frequency
                        );

                        if (notify != true){
                            Display.getInstance().vibrate(5000);
                        } 
                        Storage.getInstance().writeObject("MonitorData", decodedData);
                    }
                    else{
                System.out.println("None");
                        findCodeTextArea(c).setText("System is Good");
                    }
                    } 
                    catch (Exception ex){
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }              

    }

    }); 

    NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(r);       

    }

    }, 0, 60*1000);

}   

@Override // Stops the monitoring action.
protected void onMain_StopButtonAction(Component c, ActionEvent event) {
    super.onMain_StopButtonAction(c, event);//To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    stop = true;

    findCodeLabel(c).setText("Monitor Stopped");
    findCodeTextArea(c).setText("");
    findCodeTextArea(c).setHint("System information will show here");       
    Storage.getInstance().deleteStorageFile("MonitorData");

}


@Override // Saves the settings to storage.
protected void onSettings_SetSaveAction(Component c, ActionEvent event) {

    String Station = findSetStation(c).getText();

    Storage.getInstance().writeObject("SavedData", Station);
    String LoadStation = (String) Storage.getInstance().readObject("SavedData");
    findStationLabel(c).setText("Saved Station is " + LoadStation);


}

@Override // Sets what is saved to appear when in settings.
protected void beforeSettings(Form f) {

    String LoadStation = (String) Storage.getInstance().readObject("SavedData");
    findStationLabel(f).setText("Saved Station is " + LoadStation);
    findSetStation(f).setText(LoadStation);

    String CurrentNotify = (String) Storage.getInstance().readObject("OnOff");
    findSetNotifyLabel(f).setText("Vibration is " + CurrentNotify);
}



@Override // Sets what is saved to appear when in monitor screen.
protected void beforeMain(Form f) {
    String LoadStation = (String) Storage.getInstance().readObject("SavedData");
    findCodeLabel(f).setText(LoadStation);
    if (findCodeTextArea(f) != null){
        String foundData = (String) Storage.getInstance().readObject("MonitorData");
        findCodeTextArea(f).setText(foundData);



    }

}



@Override // Sets notification for turning vibration on.
protected void onSettings_SetNotifyOnAction(Component c, ActionEvent event) {
    notify = false;
    OnOff = "ON";
    Storage.getInstance().writeObject("NotifyOn", notify);
    Storage.getInstance().writeObject("OnOff", OnOff);
    findSetNotifyLabel(c).setText("Vibration is " + OnOff);

}


@Override // Sets notification for turning vibration off.
protected void onSettings_SetNotifyOffAction(Component c, ActionEvent event) {
    notify = true;
    OnOff = "OFF";
    Storage.getInstance().writeObject("NotifyOn", notify);
    Storage.getInstance().writeObject("OnOff", OnOff);
    findSetNotifyLabel(c).setText("Vibration is " + OnOff);

}


@Override // Sets message for monitoring or not.
protected void beforeStartPage(Form f) {
Storage.getInstance().deleteStorageFile("MonitorData");
String LoadStation = (String) Storage.getInstance().readObject("SavedData");


}

@Override // Login button pressed after entering username and password.
protected void onLogin_LoginAction(Component c, ActionEvent event) {

// Gets the username and password entered.
String userName = findUsename().getText();
String passWord = findPassword().getText();

// Establishes a conneciton to authentication.
ConnectionRequest req=new ConnectionRequest();
req.setPost(false);

req.setUrl("http://authentication.infinitevault.com/validate.php");

req.addArgument("username",userName);
req.addArgument("password",passWord);
req.addArgument("grant_type","client_credentials");

// To get the Header/Cookie information.
req.getHttpMethod();
req.setCookiesEnabled(true);

Cookie.setAutoStored(true);
Cookie.isAutoStored();

// Sends message to user that system is verifying.
findDenied(c).setText("Verifying");

NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(req);

if (req.getResponseData() != null) {
    String token = new String(req.getResponseData());
    token = token.substring(token.indexOf('=') + 1);
    System.out.println(token);

    // Checks credentials if response is denied, goes back, 
    // If response is authenticated goes to main monitor form.
    if (token.endsWith("denied")){


        /*try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);                 //1000 milliseconds is one second.
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }*/

        back();

    }
    else {
        showForm("Main",null);
    }

}




}









}//end of app
```

Comment: There is too much code here and it's unclear what you commented as the interesting points? It's also unclear if you want to parse received cookies from the server or inject an authorization cookie into the request

Comment: The comments I made in the code where it says "Need help" or "Help" is where I'm not understanding. I wish I knew how to articulate better what I'm trying to do. I have tried to use cookieReceived(Cookie c) but I don't understand it enough, and I haven't been able to find an example.

Comment: I'm using connectionRequest to connect to a URL and authenticate. when the authentication is a success the URL is sending a header that contains a cookie. I don't think I need to parse this. What I want to do is get the header/cookie and be able to send this information back to another URL that is waiting to receive that header/cookie and will allow the app to access more. I've been trying so many different things but I haven't found anything to work yet. That's why I'm reaching out. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Just override the connection request method [cookieReceived(Cookie c)](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/io/ConnectionRequest.html#cookieReceived-com.codename1.io.Cookie-) and handle the logic of each cookie there.

Comment: I understand how to override and insert cookieReceived(Cookie c) , but its the handle the logic of each cookie that I am not understanding.

Comment: That method will be invoked for every cookie returned from the server so you can keep a variable containing the state of your response and store that state there. Notice that `handleCookie` will be invoked before `readResponse` etc.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Shai, I'm still struggling, but you gave me a couple more hints. I appreciate your time.

Comment: I think the problem I'm running into is I am getting a cookie from a URL and I'm trying to send that cookie to a new URL. The new URL is waiting to receive that cookie from my app. Is this possible?

Comment: Is this how to handle the cookies with cookieReceived(Cookie c) ?

        protected void CookieReceived(Cookie c){
            Cookie cookie = null;
            cookie.getValue();
            Cookie.setAutoStored(true);
        }

Comment: I've been using the network monitor. It shows that I'm getting a cookie. Now I just need to know how to take that cookie and inject it into my request header for the other URL. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Sending a cookie is a completely different process than receiving it. What you want to do is inject a cookie by overriding `initCookieHeader` https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/io/ConnectionRequest.html#initCookieHeader-java.lang.String- just return the string with the additional set-cookie header in place

Comment: Happy to help. BTW if an answer is helpful you should upvote and if it's correct you should accept it (with the V next to it). Accepting answers as correct gives you points so you don't have as many restrictions on stack overflow

Comment: Ok. Thank you for helping me out. I was able to override connectionRequest with initCooieHeader. but I'm still not sure how to return the string with the current set-cookie header.

Comment: ConnectionRequest r = new ConnectionRequest("http://vault.infinitevault.com/cgi-bin/absentmedia?customer=" + text.toLowerCase().trim(), false){
                                 
        protected String initCookieHeader(String cookie){
            
        return getCookieHeader();
        
        } 
               
        };

Comment: I think I'm not saving the cookie in the cookieReceived(Cookie c) correctly first of all.

Then, I don't know how to get the cookie from storage to apply it to the initCookieHeader() return. 

I feel like i'm so close. but the request header is not showing the cookie that shows in the network monitor.

Comment: I suggest setting a breakpoint on that method and looking at the header string you receive. The default implementation just returns the argument you receive but you can add another header to the mix.